# Spring Propagation requires_new not working

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

I have the following scenario where I had 2 service layers taking care of inserting data in to emp table and dept table.

I have written query to fail insert on dept table i.e deptno cannot accept deptno with length > 2, hence it will not inserted into db due to DataIntegrity violation. I don't want my previous transaction to be dependent on this transaction. So used REQUIRES_NEW propagation level.

Here is my code.

```
@Component
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeDao employeeDao;

    @Autowired
    private DeptService deptService;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public boolean createEmployee() {
        employeeDao.insertEmployee();
        deptService.createDept();
        return false;
    }
}

@Component
public class DeptServiceImpl implements DeptService {

    @Autowired
    private DeptDao deptDao;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public boolean createDept() {
        deptDao.insertDepartment();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Below is Dao layer

```
@Component
public class EmployeeDaoImpl implements EmployeeDao {

    private String empInsert = "INSERT INTO emp VALUES ('1000','Ravi','CLERK','7782','1990-01-01','1235.00',NULL,'50');";

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public boolean insertEmployee() {

        int n = jdbcTemplate.update(empInsert);
        return true;
    }
}

@Component
public class DeptDaoImpl implements DeptDao {

    private String deptInsert = "INSERT INTO dept VALUES ('500','MATERIAL','ALASKA');";

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public boolean insertDepartment(){
        jdbcTemplate.update(deptInsert);
        return true;
    }

}
```

The following code is called from main class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("txrequirednew.xml");
        EmployeeService es = (EmployeeService) context.getBean("employeeServiceImpl");
        es.createEmployee();
    }
```

Below is my application context:

```
   <beans>

     <context:annotation-config/>
        <context:component-scan base-package="txrequirednew">
    </context:component-scan>

        <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SingleConnectionDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tejadb"></property>
            <property name="username" value="root"/>
            <property name="password" value="sai"/>
        </bean>

        <!-- Dao Configurations-->
        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        </bean>

        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

        <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        </bean>

    </beans>
```

When I try to execute , both the transactions are roll back. But I don't want my first transaction to be rollback.

What is that I am missing here and that's causing rollback on both transactions?
How can I fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about transaction scopes if the inner transation rollback by requires_new propagation it shouldn't effect the outer transation because

> PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW starts a new, independent "inner" transaction for the given scope. This transaction will be committed or rolled back completely independent from the outer transaction, having its own isolation scope, its own set of locks, etc. The outer transaction will get suspended at the beginning of the inner one, and resumed once the inner one has completed. ...

But you should handle the exceptions that your inner method throws it will rollback the outer transaction if you didn't handle them. The spring framework transaction will Rollback for only RunTimeException Not for other checked excpetions like SqlException.